# List is not properly shown with Motorola Razor XT910 (android 2.3)

Tags: android, user-interface, motorola

I have developed a UI for android 2.3. The UI contains a list, and some icons on bottom of the screen.

I have used `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light` in `<application/>` tag.

I have tested this app on `Samsung galaxy nexus (android 2.3)` and `galaxy nexus (android 4.0)`. It works very well.

But when I run this app on `Motorola Razor XT910 (android 2.3)`, if the list contains only few elements, i.e. it does not cover the entire screen area (i.e. screen area above the bottom icons), the empty part appears in grey color. I have also used the `background` tag for layout set as `white` color. The UI on Moto looks like this:

[image]

Please suggest me how to make this grey area as white background. I have tried alot but couldn't find the solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem occurs on motorola devices using android 2.3. The simplest fix is to set the listview height to wrap_content. More on the issue here.. [Moto Listview](http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/MOTODEV-Blog/Why-Does-My-ListView-Look-Different/ba-p/17462)

Comment: This works, but you should never set a ListView's height to `wrap_content`. Any other solutions?

Comment: @Jens What I did was subclass my ListView then called setOverscrollFooter to null in my constructor. setOverscrollFooter was added in API 9 however so you will need to use reflection

Answer (score 5):

Instead of making its height as wrap_content add the below attribute to your list view.

The problem is `android:overScrollFooter`.  Motorola has a default one set and it causes sadness.  To get rid of it, set `android:overScrollFooter="@null"` in your `ListView`.

I too faced the same problem in Motorola Devices

- Defy MB526 OS 2.3.4
- Droidx OS 2.3.4

Comment: I've been looking forever for a solution to this problem, since WRAP_CONTENT should NOT be used for ListView height, I got to a point where I've added dummy views just to occupy that space, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Set background color of your main Layout as White.It will work fine

Comment: set listview height as wrap content